# Preserving directory structure

Tags: c++, cmake

I've got a project with the following structure :

- src

  - tools
  - modules
  - core

    - shader
    - buffer
- inc

  - tools
  - modules
  - core

    - shader
    - buffer

CMake create my project with all .cpp files in a unique folder "Source files". I'm trying to preserve the original structure here is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
# Paths.
set( SRCROOT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Framework/Graphic )
set( INCROOT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/Framework/Graphic )

# Get .hpp and .cpp files.
file(
    GLOB_RECURSE
    GRAPHIC_FILES
    ${SRCROOT}
    ${INCROOT}
)

# Packages.
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

# Create the library.
add_library(Graphic ${GRAPHIC_FILES} )
```

How can I handle that ?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: In general if a tool is fighting you then do not fight back. You lose anyway. Tools are for saving time but you lose it into fighting. Choose other tool.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: I would call this as using configuration options of the tool, not fighting against it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are creating a Visual Studio project with CMake and want to visualize the source files as they are organized in the file system.

You can do that by using the CMake [source group](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3asource_group) command explicitely for files in each subfolder.

```
FILE(GLOB TOOLS_FILES
    ${SRCROOT}/src/tools/*
)
SOURCE_GROUP(tools FILES ${TOOLS_FILES})
```

... and so on. (Not tested code)

Comment: Thanks, that's work but you need to indicate all folders and subfolders so I've made a Macro using source_group :).